# How to use local variables in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have 2 list object of type of some class,

```
 class person
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

List<person> pr = new List<person>();
pr.Add(new person { id = "2", name = "rezoan" });
pr.Add(new person { id = "5", name = "marman" });
pr.Add(new person { id = "3", name = "prithibi" });

List<person> tem = new List<person>();
tem.Add(new person { id = "1", name = "rezoan" });
tem.Add(new person { id = "2", name = "marman" });
tem.Add(new person { id = "1", name = "reja" });
tem.Add(new person { id = "3", name = "prithibi" });
tem.Add(new person { id = "3", name = "prithibi" });
```

Now i have to get all the ids from **"pr"** ListObject that has **no entry** or **odd number of entries** in the **"tem"** ListObejct. using lamda.

To do this i have used,

```
HashSet<string> inconsistantIDs = new HashSet<string>(pr.Select(p => p.id).Where(p => tem.FindAll(t => t.id == p).Count == 0 || tem.FindAll(t => t.id == p).Count % 2 != 0));
```

and it works fine.

but you can see from the code i have used **tem.FindAll(t => t.id == p).Count** twice to comapre with **==0** and **%2!=0**.

> Is there any way to use **tem.FindAll(t => t.id == p).Count** once and
>   save it to a temporary variable and then compare this variable with
>   **==0** and **%2!=0**.
>
> More simply i just want to use it once for two condition here.

Comment: Please don't use subjjects as "facing issue in xxx", that will be the google-link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Use a **statement** lambda instead of an **expression** lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

```
var inconsistantIDs = new HashSet<string>(
           pr.Select(p => p.id).Where(p => 
                  {
                    var count = tem.FindAll(t => t.id == p).Count;
                    return count == 0 || count % 2 != 0;
                  }
           ));
```

Comment: Ya this works. but "count  .Count % 2 != 0" should be "count% 2 != 0". could you please just correct it. @Ahmed KRAIEM

Comment: Instead of `FindAll` i would use `Count()`. The former needs to create a new collection for every person.

Comment: @Rezoan Corrected. @Tim That's true. `var count = tem.Count(t => t.id == p);`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps simply:

```
var query = pr.Where(p => { int c = tem.Count(p2 => p.id == p2.id); return c == 0 || c % 2 != 0; });
```

returns two persons:

```
2   "rezoan"
5   "marman"
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides statement lambda you can use [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

```
HashSet<string> inconsistantIDs = new HashSet<string>(
    from p in pr
    let count = tem.FindAll(t => t.id == p).Count
    where count == 0 || count % 2 != 0
    select p.id
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashSet<string> inconsistantIDs = new HashSet<string>(
    pr.Select(p => new { Id = p.id, Cnt = tem.FindAll(t => t.id == p.id).Count() })
        .Where(p => p.Cnt == 0 || p.Cnt % 2 != 0)
        .Select(p => p.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks but its giving me error on "t.id == p" and ".Count()" should be ".Count". could you please see this issue.

Comment: Fixed. But I wouldn't use this code if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

On a side note, strictly performance wise, you would get better performance if you created a hash mapping of each ID to its count and then search it in a loop.

Right now you have a `O(n*m)` algorithm, which would be reduced to `O(n+m)`:

```
// create a map (id -> count), O(m) operation
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var p in tem)
{
    var counter = 0;
    dictionary.TryGetValue(p.id, out counter);
    counter++;
    dictionary[p.id] = counter;
}

// search the map, O(n) operation
var results = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var p in pr)
{
    var counter = 0;
    dictionary.TryGetValue(p.id, out counter);
    if (counter == 0 || counter % 2 != 0)
        results.Add(p.id);
}
```